# JQuery Datepicker ASP.NET IE7 display issue after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-7, datepicker

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 web app which has a couple of JQuery Datepickers on it. The datepicker works fine when the page first loads up and if the textbox associated with it is visible. (See attached screenshot)
However the problem comes when the textbox is not visible when the page is first loaded. When a postback occurs and the textbox is visible after the postback, the datepicker shows up as it should. However the CSS is all messed up on it. (see attached screenshot) This is on IE 7 only - IE8 and IE9 work fine.

Here is the code to initialize the datepicker:

```
function pageLoad() {
            $('#<%= dtPolExpDate.ClientID %>').unbind();
             $('#<%= dtPolExpDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
               buttonImage: '../../Common/images/calendar.gif', 
               buttonImageOnly: true, 
               showOn: 'both', 
               changeMonth: true, 
               changeYear: true, 
               showButtonPanel: true, 
               closeText: 'Close' 
             });
```

When I looked at the source, the CSS files are properly loaded up and so are the javascript files for JQuery.

I thought it was something with the masterpages, so I created a really simple aspx page - it has the same issue too. Once I click the button to show the panel with datepicker associated textbox, the datepicker is messed up. All the page has is a nested panel with the topmost panel having a simple button which when clicked shows the lower panel with the datepicker. I cant attach that aspx file here, but if needed I can take a screen shot of the code and upload it here.

**Edit**: Attached are all the [related images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ZmF.jpg) :

1. The test code
2. The datepicker before postback (which is already visible before button click)
3. The datepicker after postback (different datepicker which became visible after button click)

   Please help!

Comment: Do you have the test page up somewhere? It would help in figuring out what's going on with the css after PostBack

Comment: What do you mean by 'not visible'? `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`?

Comment: @TeckniX - I cant host the page anywhere since I dont have a ASP.NET hosting provider and my client won't let me host the page on their servers.

Comment: @JimSchubert - In the code behind, I hide the panel using panel.Visible = False which won't render that control at all in the final markup (correct me if Im' wrong).

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML for `#ipanDetails`?

Comment: If you can have the code available for download somewhere, I can compile it on my end and see why the display is out of whack. You can also try to do a bit of debugging through the dev tools and see what dimensions are missing or what jquery fails to load

Answer (score -1):

What is `pageLoad()`?

Anyway, use `$(document).ready()` e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<%= dtPolExpDate.ClientID %>').unbind();
    $('#<%= dtPolExpDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
        buttonImage: '../../Common/images/calendar.gif', 
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
        showOn: 'both', 
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true, 
        showButtonPanel: true, 
        closeText: 'Close' 
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried both pageLoad() and $(document).ready()... pageLoad() according to what I read was for partial postbacks from ASP.NET.

Comment: I don't believe they are the same: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/